# How to capture URL created by form submit in Javascript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, peoplesoft

I need help creating a URL that is clickable. We are currently using PeopleCode in peoplesoft to call an Iscript. That Iscript calls HTML. We've created this form below to build our URL

```html
<form id="form1" name="frmHostedCheckout" method="POST" action="XXXXXXXXX">
  <input type="hidden" id="api_token" name="api_token" value="XXXXXXXXX" />
  <input type="hidden" id="school_id" name="school_id" value="XXXXXX" />
  <input type="hidden" id="student_id" name="student_id" value="%BIND(:1)" />
  <input type="hidden" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="%BIND(:2)" />
  <input type="hidden" id="curriculum_id" name="curriculum_id" value="8" />
  <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="%BIND(:3)" />
  <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="%BIND(:4)" />
  <input type="hidden" id="group" name="group" value="HavenTestGroup1" />
</form>
```

We are submitting the form with the following JavaScript...

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  form1.submit(function() { 
      $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) { 
                  $('#created').html(response);
           }
      });
      return false; 
}); 
< /script>
```

When I run this we get a URL string but, it's not a clickable hyperlink. How can we make the URL clickable?

[Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRVPe.png)

Comment: I think you'll have to be clearer, the posted code is invalid, and as is, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture URL submitted by form"? do you mean the final posted URL? like: example.com/form.php?name=x&email=y ????

Comment: The code works, because I am getting a URL. It's just in text and I can't click it to go to it. I can copy and paste into a new browser window and the URL will go where I want. I want to be able to click on that URL created by this code and go to that link. Without having to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should change this line:

```
$('#created').html(response);
```

To this:

```
$('#created').html('<a href="path-to-file-or-place">' +response + '</a'>);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the response the "path-to-file-or-place"? That's what I need. The URL is the response that I want to make clickable. So this JavaScript is submitting a form that is creating the URL. I need to be able to click on that URL (the response).